# Setting SelectedItem to null does not reset the selected List item

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

The selected item of a `ListView` is not reset after setting the `SelectedItem=null` in my viewmodel.

In my XAML, the `ListView.SelectedItem` is bound to the `SelectedItem` of my viewmodel

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

`SelectedItem` is defined like this

```
LocalProductSummary _selectedItem;

public LocalProductSummary SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

After setting

```
SelectedItem=Null
```

the list item is not reset.

How to solve this in MVVM?

Comment: Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Can you change the binding: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"` to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"`?

Comment: Not working after adding Mode=TwoWay :( and I Already Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: is LocalProductSummary inherits from Bindable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectedItem is not setting null because you have null check condition in the setter method.

**Issue is here**

```
if (value != null)
{
    SelectedItem = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

You are checking that if the value is not null then set the value. Just remove the condition and check.

**Solution:**

```
LocalProductSummary _selectedItem;
public LocalProductSummary SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```